# EnumDisplayDevices() doesn't return any values in C#

Tags: c#, windows, dllimport

Before this is flagged as a duplicate: Yes, I have tried every solution I could find on StackOverflow but nothing helped.

I'm trying to set the display resolutions of my monitors via C#. I got this working for my main monitor using the `ChangeDisplaySettings()` and `EnumDisplaySettings()` Methods from `User32.dll`.

My Problem is now that I have no idea how I could set the resolution of my second monitor. I tried getting the device name via the `EnumDisplayDevices()` Method, but all I'm getting is the following output: `DeviceName =\ Monitor name =` repeated multiple times.

The code that generates this output is seen below. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

```cs
public static void GetDisplayNames()
        {
            DISPLAY_DEVICE lpDisplayDevice = new();
            lpDisplayDevice.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(lpDisplayDevice);
            DISPLAY_DEVICE monitor_name = new();
            monitor_name.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(monitor_name);

            uint devNum = 0;
            var msg = "";
            while (SystemMethods.EnumDisplayDevices(null, devNum, ref lpDisplayDevice, 0))
            {
                msg += "DeviceName =" + lpDisplayDevice.DeviceName.Trim() + '\n';

                SystemMethods.EnumDisplayDevices(lpDisplayDevice.DeviceName, 0, ref monitor_name, 0);
                msg += "Monitor name =" + monitor_name.DeviceString.Trim() + '\n';

                ++devNum;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(msg);
        }
```

```cs
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern bool EnumDisplayDevices(
[param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpDevice, 
[param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint iDevNum, 
ref DISPLAY_DEVICE lpDisplayDevice, 
[param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint dwFlags);
```

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct DISPLAY_DEVICE
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int cb;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string DeviceName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string DeviceString;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public DisplayDeviceStateFlags StateFlags;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string DeviceID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string DeviceKey;
    }

    [Flags()]
    public enum DisplayDeviceStateFlags : int
    {
        /// <summary>The device is part of the desktop.</summary>
        AttachedToDesktop = 0x1,
        MultiDriver = 0x2,
        /// <summary>The device is part of the desktop.</summary>
        PrimaryDevice = 0x4,
        /// <summary>Represents a pseudo device used to mirror application drawing for remoting or other purposes.</summary>
        MirroringDriver = 0x8,
        /// <summary>The device is VGA compatible.</summary>
        VGACompatible = 0x10,
        /// <summary>The device is removable; it cannot be the primary display.</summary>
        Removable = 0x20,
        /// <summary>The device has more display modes than its output devices support.</summary>
        ModesPruned = 0x8000000,
        Remote = 0x4000000,
        Disconnect = 0x2000000
    }
```

Comment: 3rd parameter requires the [In, Out] attributes.  Out is required because the struct is not blittable due to the strings, without it you can't see the struct change.

Comment: Sadly that didn't help. Changing it to `[In, Out] ref DISPLAY_DEVICE lpDisplayDevice` gives me the same output

Comment: Next bug is the CharSet, DISPLAY_DEVICE must be CharSet.Unicode as well.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much. I knew it was just a small thing like that. That's what happens when you copy stuff from multiple questions :)

Comment: you should post a solution, it's hidden in the comments..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following two pieces were missing:

Setting `[In, Out]` here:
`[In, Out] ref DISPLAY_DEVICE lpDisplayDevice`

And `CharSet.Unicode` here:

`[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)] public struct DISPLAY_DEVICE`